# window.history.back(); not works in sharepoint page layout

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, layout, sharepoint-online

I am trying to keep a back button in SharePoint page layout. So that on click of back button it must go to back page.

Here I have used the code. But it doesn't works.Please suggest some ideas.

`<input type="image" src="abc.png"  onclick="history.back(-1)"/>`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see your code in your post.

You can add the buttons below in page layout to make it works. To go to back page, they all works.

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.history.back()">Go Back1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="window.history.go(-1)">Go Back2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

window.history.back(-1)
window.history.go(-1)